# Last activity on the home page doesn't show whether it is modified, asked, answered, or migrated.

Tags: bug

According to the question from the body, the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4248485/888233) was migrated from Physics.SE. This means that the last activity should be something like "Migrated x mins ago (username) (reputation)", yet only the time was shown. Is this a bug, or there is no description for this activity?

[image]

After some time, it is still the same:

[image]

Comment: I am having a hard time posting a picture when viewed from an incognito page. It is the same though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, a migrated question does not show up on the Home page or the Newest Questions page with a "last activity" label.

Searching on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), I was able to find the following related bug reports about this aspect of the UI:

- [Migrated questions don't show a "last activity" status in the questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267234/986753)
- [Migrated questions don't have a user action label in the question list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304156/986753)

There is also a question asking what kind of an action on a migrated post will update the blank "last activity" label to make it show up:

- [Do newly-migrated post requires an actual "edit" to show username and time on the Meta.SE main page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261302/986753)

Comment: Considering the amount of attention that these posts have received on Meta SE (not a lot), it seems to me that it's unlikely that this bug will be addressed. Not unless the entire migration pathway gets another look from the developers' side. But that's just my guess...